# Where can I get calendar events dataset in text format?

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, nlp

I need to create a model in opennlp for identifying event information in text. I need a calendar events dataset for training this model. Can someone suggest any available open source dataset for getting calendar events?
I need sample sentences which contains calendar events in text description. For example, The IEEE conference on emerging trends and technology in communication begins from 5th Mar and continues till 10th Mar 2016 in NIT campus at Trichy.

Answer (score 3):

on [OpenDataSoft you can find ~12 datasets with calendar events](http://data.opendatasoft.com/explore/?sort=modified&refine.features=calendar) in them. You can export each of them in text format (CSV) or other format like Excel, ICS etc. You can also use the api if you prefer but it'll be in Json.

Nicolas